# Select x>0 in x when NA in x

Tags: r

```
> x
 [1] -0.0006993769            NA  0.0605337483  0.0112900315  0.0166747653  0.0498045070 -0.0120633548  0.0034724936
 [9] -0.0107294362 -0.0021350540 -0.0092103916 -0.0369649485 -0.0136530145 -0.0127135534  0.0159644319 -0.0075359604
[17]  0.0138871055  0.0226605719 -0.0118107427  0.0168362283 -0.0175228517

> x>0
 [1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[21] FALSE

> x[x>0]
 [1]          NA 0.060533748 0.011290032 0.016674765 0.049804507 0.003472494 0.015964432 0.013887105 0.022660572 0.016836228
```

do not want to get NA in `x[x>0]`, why NA were selected in this sequence

Comment: Because R doesn't know if it's `>0` or not as the value is not available. So it just returns it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `x[x > 0 & !is.na(x)]`. This will only select entries where x is different from `NA`

Comment: See comment to original post by @David Arenburg

Comment: @Jason, it would have been helpful to include this solution in your question, if you already know how to do it, in order to emphasize the "Why?" part of your question ...

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
x[na.omit(x) > 0]
```